# Unknown JavaScript Error - Only run first function

Tags: javascript, moodle

I have created two functions but the browser is running only one of them and after the rest of the functions not running.

You can see the below code. this `getElementById("loginbtn")` is running properly because it is first once but the same function put below this `getElementById("actionmenuaction-6")` function `getElementById("loginbtn")` will not work and `getElementById("actionmenuaction-6")` will work

```
document.getElementById("loginbtn").onclick = function(){
    location.href = localStorage.getItem("lastPage");
    alert("Login");
}
document.getElementById("actionmenuaction-6").onclick = function(){
    localStorage.setItem("lastPage", location.href);
}

if(document.getElementById("page-mod-page-view") || document.getElementById("page-mod-quiz- 
view") || document.getElementById("page-mod-quiz-attempt")){
    if(document.querySelector('[role="main"] form#responseform')){
        document.querySelector('[role="main"] form#responseform').scrollIntoView(true)
    } else {
        document.querySelector('[role="main"]').scrollIntoView(true);
    }  
}

//QUIZ PAGE
if(document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-view')) {
    //change button color start quiz or attemp to quiz to primary
    if(document.querySelector('.quizattempt .quizstartbuttondiv button')){
        document.querySelector('.quizattempt .quizstartbuttondiv button').className = "btn btn-secondary btn-primary"
    }
}

if(document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt')){
    if(document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .im-controls input') && document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .im-controlsinput').className.length > 0){
        document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .im-controls input').className = "submit btn btn-primary";
    } 

    if(document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .im-controls input')) {
        document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .submitbtns .mod_quiz-next-nav').className = 'mod_quiz-next-nav btn btn-secondary-imp'
    } else if(document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .submitbtns .mod_quiz-next-nav') && document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .submitbtns.mod_quiz-next-nav').className.length > 0){
        document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt div[role=main] .submitbtns .mod_quiz-next-nav').className = 'mod_quiz-next-nav btn btn-secondary'
    }

    if(document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt form .que.correct .outcome')) {
        document.querySelector('#page-mod-quiz-attempt form .correct .outcome').hidden = true;
    }
}
```

These are some console errors.

[image: Console Errors]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please zoom into the console screenshot? Or, delete the screenshot, and instead show the plain text in the question itself, formatting it with `\`\`\``.

Comment: Can you properly format your code so we can actually read it. I tried, but has all sorts of line breaks in it....

Comment: Double-check the id "actionmenuaction-6" in your html.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "actionmenuaction-6" is null
It s written in console.